# Get background-image dimensions (when not set)

Tags: css, background-image

I need to get the width and height of a background image, I've seen examples where these can be easily retrieved ONLY IF the properties are set in CSS.

Is there anyway to get width and height when they are not set in the CSS either inline or in a CSS file?

This is all I have to work with...

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(generated-by-cms.jpg);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are able to get it via CSS if you didn't set the property up. As the image is being loaded externally, the CSS file has no clue about the size. Furthermore, if you are trying to set it up via background-image, the image will be restricted by the element size.

What you can do however is load the image via Javascript (since you already have the url anyway) and then set your element to the dimensions you want. For example, let's say your HTML file contains an img tag with the id "myimg"

```
<img id="myimg"></img> <!-- an empty image -->
```

You can then set up your Javascript like this:

```
var img = new Image(); // an empty image object
img.src = 'someurl';   // image url

// this is fired after 'someurl' is loaded.
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myimg').src    = img.src;
    document.getElementById('myimg').width  = img.width;
    document.getElementById('myimg').height = img.height;
}
```

Note that you don't have to set the empty image or it's properties if you don't want to. You can manipulate img.width and img.height properties and use it elsewhere if needed.